# In a circle, is there a formula for the length of the sagitta if the chord length and arc length are known?

Tags: geometry

If I know the length of a chord of a circle and the length of the corresponding arc, but do not know the circle's radius, is there a formula by which I can calculate the length of the sagitta?

Comment: Thank you, Ted.  It seems this 63 year-old will have to brush up on "numerical methods".  Won't hurt the old brain, I guess.  Trying to solve a geometry problem at work - buckling caused by thermal expansion.

Comment: Ah, it would help to give context, as we couldn't tell if you want a Greek-geometry solution or a calculus/numerical solution. But you can easily implement what I said with a modern calculator.

Comment: Closely related to [MSE question 1313686](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313686) "How do I plot sagitta versus arc length"

Comment: Using @Ted Shifrin's formula and creating a table of values for theta, sin theta and and the ratio of the two, I cranked out the answer in Excel.  Thank you to all contributors.  Helpful and inspirational site.  Amazing what people accomplish motivated by their joy in the subject.

Comment: Roger, glad we could help. Please accept an answer so that the question doesn't stay on the “unanswered” list, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hadn't even known the term before you made me look it up.:) I don't see a way to compute it explicitly, but it is in fact uniquely determined. This is because knowing $r\theta=A$ and $r\sin\theta=B$, there is a unique $\theta$ ($0<\theta<\pi/2$) with $\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = \dfrac BA$, and then $r=\dfrac A\theta$ is unique as well. The sagitta is, of course, $r(1-\cos\theta) = r-\sqrt{r^2-B^2}$.

**Clarifying Comment**: Here $A$ is half the arclength and $B$ is half the chord length.

Comment: The one limitation, of course, is that $(\sin \theta)/\theta=c$ does not have an analytic solution (at least in terms of elementary functions). You can't have everything.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: I'm not disagreeing. I was merely arguing that there does exist a solution (by the intermediate value theorem, if you like) and that it's unique (by a bit more).

Comment: @TedShifrin You are essentially right, but a little clarification is needed. I guess you let $A$ denote the length of the arc, $B$ the lenght of the chord and $\Theta$ half the angle between the two line segments connecting the center of the circle with the two endpoints of the chord lying on the circle, We have $0 < \Theta \le \pi/2$ since for $\Theta = 0$ we do not obtain a chord. Then $A = 2\Theta r$ and $B/2 = r \cos(\pi/2 -\Theta) = r \sin (\Theta)$. This means $\sin(\Theta)/\Theta = B/A$ and now it goes as in your answer.

Comment: Yes, I was using $A$ and $B$ as half the lengths ...

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course +1.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Ted Shifrin's answer, I think that we can have a reasonable estimate of $\theta$ using the Padé approximant built at $\theta=0$
$$\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}=\frac{1-\frac{53 }{396}\theta^2+\frac{551 }{166320}\theta^4 } {1+\frac{13 }{396}\theta^2+\frac{5 }{11088}\theta^4 }$$ which is quite good for $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ (the maximum error is $2\times 10^{-6}$ at the upper bound).

Using it,solving
$$\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} =a$$ reduces to a quadratic equation in $\theta^2$ the solution of which being
$$\theta=\sqrt{6\,\frac{455 a+1855- \sqrt{35} \sqrt{-3985 a^2+130862 a+25583}}{551-75
   a} }$$

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation), you would find some interesting  numerical approaches for the solution of $\sin(\theta)=a{\theta} $.

**Edit**

If you want a much better approximation, use
$$\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}=\frac{ 1-\frac{9168 }{68821}\theta^2+\frac{433 }{133573}\theta^4} {1+\frac{11374 }{340015}\theta^2+\frac{85 }{175694}\theta^4 }$$

Answer (score 0):

These other answers are too complicated. Here is a simple way to approximate it, where s=sagitta, a=arc length, c=chord length:

$$s = 0.42 \sqrt{ a^2 - c^2}$$

If the arc is more like a full semi-circle, then the constant will be a little closer to 0.41. If the arc is more flat, then the constant will be closer to 0.43. But these are minor differences for approximations.

If you have only the sagitta and arc length and want to approximate the chord length, then you can use:

$$c = \sqrt{ a^2 - \left(\frac{s}{0.42}\right)^2 }$$

If you have only the sagitta and chord length and want to approximate the arc length:

$$a = \sqrt{ c^2 + \left(\frac{s}{0.42}\right)^2 }$$